# Why the size is returning wrong number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Following is my jQuery code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    function add_title() {
        var title_no = $('#doc_title div').size();
        alert(title_no);
    } 
</script>
```

Following is my concerned HTML code:

```
<ul>
<li>
<div id="doc_title" class="answer-block">
<a id="add_more_title" class="c-gray-btn c-add-btn" onclick="add_title(); return false;" name="add_more_title" href="#">
<ol>
<div id="ttl1">
<li class="ans_li">
<li class="ans_li">
<li class="ans_li">
<li class="ans_li">
<input type="hidden" value="22" name="pt_doc_id[0]">
<input type="hidden" value="sahil_kumar.pdf" name="pt_doc_old_file_iname[0]">
</div>
<div id="ttl2">
<li class="ans_li">
<li class="ans_li">
<li class="ans_li">
<li class="ans_li">
<input type="hidden" value="23" name="pt_doc_id[1]">
<input type="hidden" value="vijay_singh.doc" name="pt_doc_old_file_iname[1]">
</div>
</ol>
<a id="add_more_title" class="c-gray-btn c-add-btn" onclick="add_title(); return false;" name="add_more_title" href="#">
<p class="fade">Note * (Image size should be less then 1 mb and allowed image types are jpg, jpeg, gif, png .)</p>
</div>
</li>
<li>
</ul>
```

The alert is coming as 4, actually the alert should come as 2. Why this is happening? can anyone help me in this regard please? In short it's giving double of no. of divs present within div with `id= doc_title`. That is if 1 div is present witin then the alert is coming as 2, if the no. is f it's alerting 8.

Comment: I think you should call only the direct children like `var title_no = $('#doc_title').children('div').size();`

Comment: They are children of `<ol>` though, not direct children of `#doc_title`.

Comment: i dont see any closing `</a>` tags

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, fix it first.

Comment: It's working, here, exactly as you've provided...: http://jsfiddle.net/c8E6u/

Comment: I guess, you have another `div#doc_title` somewhere on the page.

Comment: The html source code is heavily currupt, you might want to fix it. many closing tags are missing: </a> and </li>, the ordered lists embrace div elements ...

Answer (score 2):

From the problem it appears that you have that dom structure twice in your code. **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c8E6u/3/)**.

To particularly select this dom, you need to determine that how does this dom differ from existing dom in terms of its dom structure(i.e. what difference two dom have in terms of their child and parent structure).May be find out the parent with id/class and try getting the dom. **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c8E6u/4/)**

```
var title_no = $('#doc_title div').length;
var title_no1 = $('ul li #doc_title div').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Please try this:
> ```

```
$("#add_more_title").click( function() {
    var title_no = $('#doc_title div').size(); alert(title_no); 

});
```